# Suspend function blocks main thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-coroutines

I'm having a hard time understanding coroutines. This is a very simple setup. Both `longComputation` and `delay` are suspend functions. The first one blocks the main thread, the latter doesn't. Why?

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    val result = longComputation() // Blocks
    delay(10_000) // Doesn't block
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the task on a different thread context, such as `withContext(IO)`?

Comment: Yes, this works. I guess I have to go back to the basics. Does `delay` also switch the  dispatcher internally? Can't say I understand the sourcecode of `delay`

Comment: No delay doesn’t need another dispatcher since it’s a real suspending function which does not block the thread at any time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That depends. What does `longComputation` do exactly? 
When you mark a function as `suspend`, this does not mean you can't include blocking code in it. For instance, have a look at this one:

```
suspend fun blockingSuspendFunction(){
    BigInteger(1500, Random()).nextProbablePrime()
}
```

The code inside the suspend function is obviously something that utilizes the CPU and blocks the caller.
**By convention**, this should not be done because if you call a suspend function, you *expect* it to **not** block the thread:

> Convention: suspending functions do not block the caller thread. (https://medium.com/@elizarov/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761)

To make such a function "behave as a suspending function", the blocking has to be dispatched onto another worker thread, which (by recommendation) should happen with `withContext`:

```
suspend fun blockingSuspendFunction() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    BigInteger.probablePrime(2048, Random())
}
```

Comment: Exactly what you mentioned. It was a heavy blocking computation. Suddenly the concept of "continuation" makes sense to me.